# Error message when trying to create a simple site using CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

This is the add.ctp file that's producing the error

```
<?php
echo $form->create('Category');
echo $form->input('name');
echo $form->end('Save Post');
?>
```

This is the CategoriesController.php file associated with add.ctp

```
<?php

class CategoriesController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Categories';

    function index() {
        $this->set('categories', $this->Category->find('all'));
    }

    function add() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            if ($this->Category->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your category has been saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I keep receiving the following error message:

> `Call to a member function create() on a non-object`

Comment: Please post your controller code for the view add.ctp.  'Category' should refer to a Model named Category, have you created that?

Comment: what version of cakephp are you using?

Comment: Yes, I've created the Category model.  I'm using version 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using 2.X, are you assigning `$this->Form` to `$form` before using it?

Comment: I didn't.  Where would I place the code and would it be $form=$this->Form?  I'm very new to this.

Comment: before using it on the view, or replace $form with $this->Form

Answer (score 0):

You are using code corresponding to cakephp 1.x

```
<?php
echo $this->form->create('Category');
echo $this->form->input('name');
echo $this->form->end('Save Post');
?>
```

is the correct way in cakephp 2.x.

[cakephp docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#formhelper)